# Typecheck method decorator factory

Tags: typescript

This is the [decorator example in the typescript website](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html):

```
class Greeter {
    greeting: string;
    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }

    @enumerable(false)
    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
}

function enumerable(value: boolean) {
    return function (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
        descriptor.enumerable = value;
    };
}
```

As you can see, the decorator factory returns a function that accepts the target and property key to get the method property.

Now, I want to create a decorator that accepts a method and type checks that the passed method and method property has the same type:

```
const auxMethod = (str: string) => 'a';
class Greeter {
    @myMethod(auxMethod)
    greet(str: string) {
        return "Hello, " + str;
    }
}
```

As you can see auxMethod and greet has the same type. Is it possible to type check this in typescript?

If decorators passed the actual method in the inner decorator factory it would be simple with generics:

```
function myMethod<T> (handler: T) {
    return function (target: T) {
    };
}
```

but since target and propertyKey is dynamic it can't.